# Js collision detector - hit the wall vs. hit the floor (difference)

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm making a small game with one player and blocks that builds up the environment. The problem I'm having is knowing the difference between when the player hits the ground (the top of a block), and hitting a wall (the side of the block).

So far the player can walk on the ground just fine, but when he meets a wall, he immediately jumps to the top of that block.

This is my collision detector:

```js
function collisionDetector(){
  if(myPlayer.y + myPlayer.h > c.height){ //Bottom of the canvas
    myPlayer.vy = 0;
    myPlayer.ay = 0;
    myPlayer.y = c.height - myPlayer.h;
    myPlayer.onGround = true;
    console.log(myPlayer.y + myPlayer.h, c.height);
  }
  if(myPlayer.x + myPlayer.w >= c.width){ //right side of canvas
    myPlayer.x = c.width - myPlayer.w;
    myPlayer.vx = 0;
  }
  if(myPlayer.x <= 0){ //Left side of canvas
    myPlayer.x = 0;
    myPlayer.vx = 0;
  }

  function hitTest(a,b){ //hitTest between two objects
    if(a.y + a.h > b.y && a.y < b.y + b.h && a.x + a.w > b.x && a.x < b.x + b.w){
      return true;
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){ //Loop through blocks
    if(hitTest(myPlayer, blocks[i])){ //If it touches a block
        myPlayer.y = blocks[i].y - myPlayer.h;
        myPlayer.onGround = true; //onGround = ready to jump
    }
  }
}
```

I realized that I'm setting the players y pos to be on top of what ever block it hits, but I cannot figure out a solution to this problem. Can anyone help me or at least lead me in the right direction? Thanks!

(Let me know if you need more of the code)

PS: the player is just a head. No body hiding behind the blocks.

[image: A small taste of what is going on]

Comment: Instead of checking the whole rect, you can check the bottom edge of the player against the block (if true then is on ground), and the side edges of the player against blocks (if true then is against wall).

Comment: What framework are you using? Or is it just plain JS?

Comment: @Jorjon this is pure JS

Comment: @Jorjon could you show me how that code could look? Because I dont understand how that would work without checking the x collision when he touches the ground. Wouldt it be true even though it is not in reach in the x direction.

Comment: see my answer, I have added a fully working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, what you need to do is to check collision between many points in the player.

In the snippet you can show many points represented in the player.

- Bottom almost-left and almost-right (in blue), check against below blocks. They are not fully left or right, in order to prevent a race condition which will allow the player to *climb* walls. In that case, if the player is pushing against a wall and jumping, the collider will detect both side collision and bottom collision as true, then the player will quickly move to the top until there are no more blocks.
- Left and right points (in black), check against edges of the blocks. This is just a point instead of two like the bottom edge, because we don't need more for this particular case. One more for each side could be easily added to get a better detection.
- Top point (in red) checks against the top blocks. This is in the middle in order to allow the player a more easy way to tranverse the map. If this is not needed, you would need to add one more point like in the bottom edge (but never reaching the far edge, because that will generate a race condition).

So in summary, to have a good collision detection based on points (instead of raycasts), you need to detect the player like if it where a rounded shape, in order to prevent strange behaviours.

You can player around with the map layout by altering the `layout` variable. `0`'s are empty space, `1`'s are brown blocks and `2`'s are green blocks.

The `collisionDetector` fuction has comments to understand what's going on.

Also I have added a jump feature since I understand you would need that as well.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

// map layout
const layout = 
`000000001
001000001
000000101
100110111
222222222`;

// convert layout to blocks
const blocks = [...layout].reduce((a, c, i) => {
  if (i === 0 || c === "\n") a.push([]);
  if (c === "\n") return a;
  const y = a.length - 1;
  const row = a[y];
  const x = row.length;
  row.push({x: x * 32, y: y * 32, t:c, w:32, h:32});
  return a;
}, []).reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), []);

// player starting position
const myPlayer = {x: 32*1.5, y: 0, h: 32, w: 16, onGround: true};
const gravity = -1;
let pkl = 0, pkr = 0;
let pvely = 0;

function render() {

  // player logic
  const pvelx = pkr + pkl;
  const speed = 2;
  myPlayer.x += pvelx * speed;
  myPlayer.y -= pvely;
  if (pvely > -2) pvely += gravity;


  const debugColliders = collisionDetector();
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // player render
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFD9B3';
  ctx.fillRect(myPlayer.x, myPlayer.y, myPlayer.w, myPlayer.h);

  renderLayout();

  debugColliders();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function renderLayout() {
  const colors = {'1': '#A3825F', '2': '#7FAC72'}
  
  blocks.forEach(b => {
      if (+b.t > 0) {
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[b.t];
        ctx.fillRect(b.x, b.y, b.w, b.h);
      }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    pkr = 1;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    pkl = -1;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    if (myPlayer.onGround)
      pvely = 8;
      myPlayer.onGround = false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }

});

window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    pkr = 0;
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    pkl = 0;
  }
});


function collisionDetector(){
  const p = myPlayer;
  const playerTop = p.y;
  const playerLeft = p.x;
  const playerRight = playerLeft + p.w;
  const playerBottom = playerTop + p.h;
  const playerHalfLeft = playerLeft + p.w * .25;
  const playerHalfRight = playerLeft + p.w * .75;
  const playerHMiddle = playerLeft + p.w * .5;
  const playerVMiddle = playerTop + p.h * .5;

  if(playerBottom > c.height){ //Bottom of the canvas
    p.vy = 0;
    p.ay = 0;
    p.y = c.height - p.h;
    p.onGround = true;
  }
  if(playerRight >= c.width){ //right side of canvas
    p.x = c.width - p.w;
    p.vx = 0;
  }
  if(playerLeft <= 0){ //Left side of canvas
    p.x = 0;
    p.vx = 0;
  }

  blocks.forEach(b => { //Loop through blocks
    if (b.t === "0") return; // If not collidable, do nothing
    const blockTop = b.y;
    const blockLeft = b.x;
    const blockRight = blockLeft + b.w;
    const blockBottom = b.y + b.h;

    // Player bottom against block top
    if ((playerBottom > blockTop && playerBottom < blockBottom) && // If player bottom is going through block top but is above block bottom.
    ((playerHalfLeft > blockLeft && playerHalfLeft < blockRight) || // If player left is inside block horizontal bounds
    (playerHalfRight > blockLeft && playerHalfRight < blockRight))) { // Or if player right is inside block horizontal bounds
      p.y = blockTop - p.h;
      p.onGround = true;
    }

    // Player top against block bottom
    if ((playerTop < blockBottom && playerTop > blockTop) && // If player top is going through block bottom but is below block top.
    ((playerHMiddle > blockLeft && playerHMiddle < blockRight))) { // If player hmiddle is inside block horizontal bounds
      p.y = blockBottom;
      p.onGround = false;
    }

    // Player right against block left, or player left against block right
    if (playerVMiddle > blockTop && playerVMiddle < blockBottom) { // If player vertical-middle is inside block vertical bounds
      if ((playerRight > blockLeft && playerRight < blockRight)) { // If player vmiddle-right goes through block-left
        p.x = blockLeft - p.w;
      } else if ((playerLeft < blockRight && playerRight > blockLeft)) { // If player vmiddle-left goes through block-right
        p.x = blockRight;
      }
    }

  });
  return function debug() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(playerLeft, playerVMiddle, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillRect(playerRight, playerVMiddle, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(playerHMiddle, playerTop, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(playerHalfLeft, playerBottom, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillRect(playerHalfRight, playerBottom, 1, 1);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
html, body{ width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { background: #7AC9F9; display: block;  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later today! I set will set it as the right answer as soon as I see that it works and I understand it.

Comment: Hey, I tried the collision detector you introduced and i think I understand the consept, but it doesnt work. I think there might be something wrong with another part of my code, as my character all of a sudden starts flying cross the map and glitching out totaly. Is it posible that I could maybe get your mail or something, so you could take a look at my code? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on Fiddle? Or maybe try using my code as the base and start adding your stuff piece by piece checking on each step, so you easily detect what is wrong.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with `myPlayer.vy` and `myPlayer.ay`

Comment: Actually, I think I should just set your answer as the right answer, because im just about able to test the collision before the character starts acting up. But when it comes to my problem, it seems like there is i slightly random «timer» that activate the glitch. Really hard to describe. Is there a way to show you the entire code?

Comment: I made a Fiddle for you. It would really help me out if you could just take a look at it. Thank you so much! https://jsfiddle.net/benjamhw/79rkjj5z/4/

Comment: Well that's kind of a different question, you should really open a new one. But anyway, the issue is that you are incrementing the y velocity without a limit, so eventually the speed makes the player go through the floor. You shoud change `myPlayer.vy += myPlayer.g;` to `myPlayer.vy += myPlayer.vy < 5 && myPlayer.g;`

Comment: Thank you. I know its a different problem, but I wasnt sure how to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `block[i].type` attribute. For instance if `block[i].type=='floor'`  then make player stay on floor. If for another instance `block[i].type=='wall'` then make it stop moving through the wall. When `block[i].type=='brick'` or square or block or whatever, them it's a mixture of two.

Another part to be edited is when you check the collisions. What if you have only one-direction collision? What I am saying is maybe use `or` instead of `and` in this part `if(a.y + a.h > b.y && a.y < b.y + b.h && a.x + a.w > b.x && a.x < b.x + b.w){`

Also you could check each collision separately, like

```
function hitTest(a,b){ //hitTest between two objects
  var collisions = {up: false, down: false, left: false, right: false};
  collisions.up = (a.y + a.h > b.y ) || collisions.up
  collisions.down = (a.y < b.y + b.h ) ||collisions.down
  collisions.right = ( a.x + a.w > b.x) || collisions.right
  collisions.left = (a.x < b.x + b.w) || collisions.left
  return collisions
}

var escapeFrom = {
  down: function(player, block){
     player.y = block.y + block.h;
     player.onGround = true; //onGround = ready to jump
  },
  up: function(player, block){
  // you logic to escape from hitting the ceiling
  },
  // and for the next 2
  left: function(player, block) {},
  right: function(player, block){}
}

// Now here you check whether your player hits blocks
for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){ //Loop through blocks
    cls = hitTest(myPlayer, blocks[i]) //If it touches a block
    Object.keys(cls).map(function(direction, ind){
         if (cls[direction]){
           // call escape from function to escape collision
            escapeFrom[direction](myPlayer, blocks[i]);
         }
    })
}
```

This is highly unoptimized, the whole your code is unoptimized, but at least it can help to move further.

Comment: Well Thanks, but as you may see on the picture, som of the walls are both walls and floors, so I dont think this would work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: It didnt work. I tried, and now it wont even stop when he hits the ground.

Comment: @Benjamhw i edited my comment. have a try. Also, could you select my answer as long as it is right.  Thank you

Comment: I will test, Thanks